# Are there any alternatives to numerous elifs in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I have the need for calling a function based on strings in lines of a text file.
The snippet below only shows 3 elifs, but in reality I will need 25, and that just seems
wrong. Is there an alternative to having so many elifs? I considered a dictionary where the keys
are the strings and the values are the commands to be called, but I am unsure how to make
a function call from fetchng a dictionary item. Also, this gets complicated by the fact that
each command (function) will have varying numbers of values to be passed into them - anywhere
from 1 to 8.

```
def command_a():
    <Do something>

(then, similar functions for commands b, c, d)

def tooManyElifs():
    with open(MyScript, 'r') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if "<CommandA" in line:
                command_a()
            elif "<CommandB" in line:
                command_b()
            elif "<CommandC" in line:
                command_c()
            elif "<CommandD" in line:
                command_d()
            <and so on...>
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Or just use the commands as keys in a dictionary; no need for regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dispatch data structure:

```
command_map = [
    ("<CommandA", command_a),
    ("<CommandB", command_b),
    ("<CommandC", command_c),
    ...
]
...
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        for cmd, func in command_map:
            if cmd in line:
                func()
```

You could also use a dictionary, but since you don't need to search by key, that didn't seem to add any value.

Answer (score 0):

An if/elif/else chain is fine for this, but you could also use structural pattern matching (Python 3.10+) with a custom string class that overrides `__eq__` to do contains.  This is a simplified example, replace `print()` with your function calls:

```py
class Contains(str):
    """Override str.__eq__ to check whether a string contains a substring."""
    def __eq__(self, pattern):
        return pattern in self


line = "<CommandC"

match Contains(line):
    case "<CommandA":
        print("A")
    case "<CommandB":
        print("B")
    case "<CommandC":
        print("C")
    case _:
        print("Unknown command!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary or list to map command strings with functions, include a fallback function that doesn't do anything for cases where no command is found.  For each line use the next() function to get a function and execute it.

```
commands = { "<CommandA": command_a,
             "<CommandB": command_b,
             "<CommandC": command_c,
             "":          lambda:0}

with open(MyScript, 'r') as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        next(fn for cmd,fn in commands.items() if cmd in line)()
```